# Start project view tree from deeper folder

Tags: intellij-idea

My project is very deep and it causes the Project view to become quite cumbersome to use as I can only see the start of the files when I keep the pane at a reasonable width.

See my [current structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7QlK5.png).

The current scope only show source files and I know they only start after a certain folder (after the red line in the screenshot).
How can I hide everything before it?

Answer (score 1):

The best you can get (afaik) is to create a custom scope that only matches the files you need.
The scope is selectable in the project view dropdown (1)
If you also disable the show modules option (2) it also flattens your tree a little bit more.
[image: configuration]